# Parse date-time field defined in Swagger file

Tags: api, date, datetime, swagger-2.0

I have an API written in Swagger 2.0 that says an entity has a property called `when` of type `date-time`:

```
properties:
  when:
    type: string
    format: date-time
```

I don't know how to parse the string. How should I expect the date-time format to looks like? I cannot find this in the Swagger 2.0 documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the Open API 2.0 spec, the `date-time` should be defined by [RFC3339](http://xml2rfc.ietf.org/public/rfc/html/rfc3339.html#anchor14).

For example:

1. 2016-03-22T21:03:41
2. 1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z
3. 1990-12-31T15:59:60-08:00

> I don't know how to parse the string.

This would depend on the language you're using. In JavaScript, `Date.parse(dateString)` can easily parse the string. Or in Java, you can refer to [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date) to know how to parse the date string.

Comment: Ok, I mean, I know to to parse a String to Date in Java. I was wondering which format I should expect for the date. Now I know. Yeah, of course the one that implements the API can do a mistake. Then I cannot parse the response :)

Comment: RFC3339 dates require the time-offset component, so your example #1 does not comply.